# Update jProgressBar from another thread

Tags: java

I'm new in java. I'm trying to understand thraeads and timers in java. It was big problem for me to undate ProgressBar from another thread. I read many posts and found answers. So can you say is this the best way to resolw my task. So, what I want is to run second thread and when it's done, stop progress bar and change text on the button. So I creat Frame with button and progress bar in **Test** class:

[image]

After I realize action listener for Button to run second thread:

```
       public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {



              RunBg thread = new RunBg();

            .... 
    // declaration for button, progressbar and main() method
    ....

            private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      


// needed to check is the thread running at first time else creat new object and rund hread again cause thread can be executed once

                    if(thread == null){
                        thread = new RunBg();
                    }

                    if (jProgressBar1.isIndeterminate()) {
                        jProgressBar1.setIndeterminate(false);
                        jButton1.setText("Run!");
                        thread.suspend();
                    } else {

                        jButton1.setText("Working...");
                        jProgressBar1.setIndeterminate(true);

// let us know is the second thread running or nope so we can know resume it or pause
                        if (thread.isAlive()) {
                            thread.resume();
                        } else {
                            thread.start();
                        }

                        timer.start();


                    }


                } 



    /*
    Then I creat timer to know is my thread still alive else change Progress bar and button

    */

       Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if(!thread.isAlive()){

                            thread.stop();
                            jProgressBar1.setIndeterminate(false);
                            jButton1.setText("Запустить!");
                            timer.stop();
                        //    thread.interrupt();
                            thread = null;

                        }
                    }
        });  


      ...
    // end of class
    }
```

And my second class for another thread named RunBG:

```
public class RunBg extends Thread{

    int i = 0;

    public void run(){

        while(i<20000){
                System.out.println(">>>"+i);
                i++;
            }
        System.out.println("<<<Finished>>>");


    }

}
```

Everythig works fine , but I have question. Is there a better way to realize my task or maybe I made some mistakes. Also I thik that my code will help another beginners who looking for help to understand how it's work.

Comment: Check out `SwingWorker` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Comment: As I understood it's like AsyncTask in Android. Is it so?

Comment: Similar, yes. They key here is to not block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). This will cause your GUI to freeze. So what it allows you to do is do work on a separate thread and call code on the EDT to update the GUI.

Comment: Thanx for comment! I will try SwingWorker and will rewrite my code using it.